# Proof to show function f satisfies Lipschitz condition when derivatives f' exist and are continuous

Tags: analysis

**The question is as follows:**

> > **Given** a function $f$, 2 known information:
> >      (1) $f'(x)$ exist
> >      (2) $f'(x)$ are continuous
> >
> > **Goal:**  function $f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition on any bounded interval $[a,b]$

**Here is my attempt:**

**1/** Recall Lipschitz condition:  a function $f$ satisfies Lipschitz if there is a real number $N$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq N  |x - y|$

**2/** First, I plan to show this :

> (*) Knowing $f'(x)$ is continuous at any point $x \implies f'(x)$ is
>   bounded at some neighborhood about $x$

Using definition of continuity on $f'(x)$, I say that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that for any $y$, we have $|x - y| < \delta => |f'(x) - f'(y)| < \epsilon$.

After some works, I realize that $f'(y)$ is in the neighborhood of $(f'(x) - \epsilon, f'(x) + \epsilon)$.

So if I let my $N = max${$f'(x) + \epsilon, -f'(x) + \epsilon$}, I reach the conclusion that $f'(x)$ is bounded (at least below)

3/ Then, I plan to use (*) to say this :

> If function $f$ has a derivative $f'$ such that $f'$ is bounded by
>   some number K $ \implies f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition on any interval
>   [a,b]

I plan to use the Mean Value Theorem, provided that by (*), there is a derivative $f'(x) < K$ where $x$ is in between some $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $[a,b]$

Would someone please check if my ideas are correct?

I feel very shaky about part 2 of my work.  If the derivative is bounded, then I think the proof will be way easier.  But to conclude that continuous $\implies $ bounded, I'm not sure if I can claim such thing .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Continuous function $g$ in a compact interval $[a,b]$ implies $g$ bounded in $[a,b]$. (This part I make a bit more general than yours)

Consider the set $X=\{x\in[a,b]: g|[a,x] \text{ is bounded }\}$. Show that $a\in X$ and $\sup X\in X$ then $b=\sup X$ so $b\in X$.

2) Bounded derivative implies Lipschitz.

If $|f'(x)|\leq K$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, in particular for any $x,y\in[a,b]$ such that $x\neq y$ we have

$$\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|=|f'(c)|\leq K$$

for some $c\in[x,y]$ by MVT. Then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|$.

Comment: may be i am missing a point ,but wont g|[a,x] for a<x<b be bounded ? if g|[a,b] is bdd?

Comment: @rohit yes, $g|[a,b]$ bounded iff for each $x\in[a,b]$ $g|[a,x]$ is bounded.

Comment: @Gastón Burrull What if $|f'(x)| \leqslant K$ for all $x \in (a, b)$ instead of  $[a, b]$. Is the proof then still correct?

Comment: yes, youre right