# Let P be a polynomial of degree $n,\,\,\, n\ge 2.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck with the following problem:

> Let P be a polynomial of degree $n,\,\,\, n\ge 2.$ Then I have to prove that the initial value problem $u'(t)=P(u(t)),\,\,u(0)=1$ has always
>
> 1. a unique solution in any interval containing $0$.
> 2. no  solution in any interval containing $0$ for some P.

I have to check which of the aforementioned statements is *correct*?

My Attempt:  Without loss of generality,I take $P(u)=u^n$. Then $u'(t)=P(u(t)),\,\,u(0)=1$ yields to $u^{1-n}=(1-n)t+1.$ Now,if I take $n=2,\,\,$ then we get $\,\,\frac1u=-t+1.$

Now,I am stuck. Can someone help?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain a little more how assuming $\,P\,$ is a monic monomial is really "WLOG"...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "without loss of generality,I take $P(u)=u^n$" is a legal move in this game. Try to reason along the following lines:

1. A polynomial function is differentiable, with continuous derivative.
2. A differentiable function with bounded derivative [is Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382820/79365).
3. The [Picard existence/uniqueness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) applies when the right-hand side is a Lipschitz function of $u$.