# Integral continuity in mean

Tags: real-analysis

Let f : $R^n\to R$ be a differentiabile function in all points,with uniformly limited gradient .Prove that the gradient is continous in mean, that is:
$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{\omega_n*r^n} \int_{B_r(x)} (\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)) dy=0$
($\omega_n$ is the lebesgue measure of unitary ball $B_1(0)$ of $R^n$ )

Comment: if the gradient is continous it's trivial but in general no. how can it be related with the uniformly limitated gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniformly *bounded* is the correct term. This assumption is made so that the gradient can be integrated; in general the gradient of a differentiable function can be non-integrable. We'll also need it in order to use the fundamental theorem of calculus in the proof: bounded gradient [implies $f$ is Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/382818/), hence absolutely continuous on every line.

Fix $x$. By subtracting an appropriate linear function from $f$ we ensure that $f(x)=0$ and $\nabla f(x)=0$. Then $f(y)=o(|y-x|)$. Let's prove that $\int_{B_r(x)} f_1 =o(r^n)$ where $f_1$ is the derivative in the direction of $x_1$. Fix $x_2,\dots,x_n$ and integrate in the $x_1$ direction. The fundamental theorem of calculus says that the integral is the difference of two values of $f$, which is $o(r)$. Integration over the remaining $(n-1)$ coordinates yields $o(r)\omega_{n-1}r^{n-1}$, which is $o(r^n)$ as required.

Comment: ok,but how can I prove with a counterexample that it doesn't work if we integrate $|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)|$

Comment: @user62138 Try $f(x)=x^2\sin (1/x)$ in one dimension. It's not easy to integrate $|f'|$ over $[-h,h]$ explicitly, but it's approximately $|\cos (1/x)|$, which averages to $2/\pi$.